# Rundeck: populate drop down based on previous user input

Tags: drop-down-menu, rundeck

I am looking for something like this in rundeck- User selects the drop down menu A or B
If A then populate the next dropdown with A1 A2 A3 else if B then B1 B2 B3.
It seems its possible with [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/defining-job-options.html#cascading-remote-options) But it's  not at all clear how to accomplish this. 
Thank in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a good practical example:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rundeck-discuss/NrVzI9Kx8zw/Yg2yP8MpDwAJ

Basically, you need point some JSON file to others to work, check it.